# Scaling rectangle from one side 2D unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem because of the rectangle which isnt moving. Here is my code:

```
void Update()
{
    MakeHungerRectangleScaleDown ();
}


public void MakeHungerRectangleScaleDown ()
{
    HungerRectangleScaling = HungerRectangle.localScale;
    HungerRectangleScaling.x -= HungerRectangleScaleDelay;
    HungerRectangle.Translate(HungerRectangleScaleDelay / 2, 0, 0);
    HungerRectangle.localScale = HungerRectangleScaling;
}
```

so i want the rectangle to scale from one side?? help ?? its in 2d

Comment: Can you add in your code sample how `HungerRectangleScaling` and `HungerRectangleScaleDelay` are defined? Also, if you add `print("Before: " + HungerRectangle.localScale);` (at the start of your scale function) and `print("After: " + HungerRectangle.localScale);` (at its end), what does it print in the console?

Comment: i already figured it out. but thanks for the reply